# How to access subsite pages and posts in wordpress multipage setup?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I've got a tricky situation.

A customer wants a multisite Wordpress installation in order to easily map three domains to their regions of his website. Done.

All three subpages should share the same theme with different color schemes. Done, multisite and a child-theme are a great combination.

All three subpages should share the same menu. Done, there are plugins for global menus.

In this menu, there should be links from all three subpages. How to do that? When creating the menu in one page, I will always have access to the site's pages, not to those of the other sites. Any idea how to achieve this? Is there a plugin or a hack I've missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you redirect the other domains to one domain which hosts the wordpress site? And maybe fiddle a bit with language settings if these regions require it? Depending on language you could load a different colored theme...

Comment: Main reason for not doing this, is that the customer needs those domains for SEO purposes. They have a fairly good pagerank and should be used in the future. So not going with multisite is not an option. Sadly.

Comment: Have you seen the networkwide menu plugin? http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/networkwide-menu/

Comment: Yes, this is the plugin I used. Problem is: I cannot add links from the subsites - only pages from the main site. Of course I could add the pages as links, but then it won't make them active when they are visited.

Comment: I do not think that exists yet... You will have to write a plugin which overrides the functionality to check if the link is active to also check if the current full url is the same as the full url in the menu. Maybe by altering the code of he aforementioned network wide menu plugin

Comment: Just to complete this for those who may have the same problem: We ended up with a turn of strategy. We discarded the multi site thing and went back to a single site. Was easier then to change the whole way wordpress works with multisites. But thanks for your help!